# Updating a RDD in a loop

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am updating a RDD in a loop.
Since RDDs are immutable, a new RDD is created in every iteration. Is there a way which deletes the old RDD and persists only the latest RDD.

Comment: Can you paste the code what you are doing?

Comment: Why you don't do this: `rdd = rdd.map(lambda somthing)`? This will update the actual rdd with no problem.